# showing tags inside tableviewcell from JSON Data

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, taglist

I am creating app Using `Swift` and i want show some tags inside `UITableViewCell` with JSON Parsing here is the screenshot which i want to do in my app

[Here is the screen shot i want to do like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/la6kQ.jpg)

as you see in screenshot Flat1, Flat2 is tags which i want to show inside UITableVieCell and for showing tags i have used below

[This is the TagListView Which i have used](https://github.com/ElaWorkshop/TagListView)

Here is my JSON Data which comes from WebService

```
{
  "success": "1",
  "data": [
    {
      "fk_project_surveyors_id": "1",
      "number": 1,
      "created_date": "2020-04-17 10:09:57",
      "sub_cores": [
        {
          "sub_cores_title": "Flat 1"
        }
      ],
      "signature": "img_sFZuFpUd011587136197.png",
      "name": "Sean Clancy",
      "inspections_id": "4",
      "fk_user_id": "1",
      "fk_cores_id": "12",
      "survey_date": "2020-04-12"
    },
    {
      "fk_project_surveyors_id": "1",
      "number": 2,
      "created_date": "2020-04-29 12:55:45",
      "sub_cores": [
        {
          "sub_cores_title": "Flat 1"
        },
        {
          "sub_cores_title": "Flat 2"
        }
      ],
      "signature": "img_Ptw0bvSGfR1588182945.png",
      "name": "Sean Clancy",
      "inspections_id": "6",
      "fk_user_id": "1",
      "fk_cores_id": "12",
      "survey_date": "2020-04-12"
    },
    {
      "fk_project_surveyors_id": "1",
      "number": 3,
      "created_date": "2020-05-06 06:08:11",
      "sub_cores": [
        {
          "sub_cores_title": "Flat 1"
        }
      ],
      "signature": "img_FSUTzxT4221588763291.png",
      "name": "Sean Clancy",
      "inspections_id": "7",
      "fk_user_id": "1",
      "fk_cores_id": "12",
      "survey_date": "2020-04-12"
    },
    {
      "fk_project_surveyors_id": "1",
      "number": 4,
      "created_date": "2020-06-15 04:25:16",
      "sub_cores": [
        {
          "sub_cores_title": "Flat 1"
        }
      ],
      "signature": "img_EVqcz58zN11592213116.png",
      "name": "Sean Clancy",
      "inspections_id": "8",
      "fk_user_id": "1",
      "fk_cores_id": "12",
      "survey_date": "2020-04-12"
    },
    {
      "fk_project_surveyors_id": "1",
      "number": 5,
      "created_date": "2020-06-21 11:04:56",
      "sub_cores": [
        {
          "sub_cores_title": "Flat 1"
        }
      ],
      "signature": "img_3ySNyhAjYd1592755496.png",
      "name": "ron",
      "inspections_id": "10",
      "fk_user_id": "1",
      "fk_cores_id": "12",
      "survey_date": "2020-04-12"
    },
    {
      "fk_project_surveyors_id": "1",
      "number": 6,
      "created_date": "2020-06-21 11:05:44",
      "sub_cores": [
        {
          "sub_cores_title": "Flat 1"
        }
      ],
      "signature": "img_ILSykgAIW71592755544.png",
      "name": "ron2",
      "inspections_id": "11",
      "fk_user_id": "1",
      "fk_cores_id": "12",
      "survey_date": "2020-04-12"
    }
  ],
  "message": ""
}
```

as you see in JSON Data each item has sub_cores array and from that `sub_cores_title` i want to show inside `TagListView` which is inside `UITableViewCell`

Here is my model structure which i have used to parse above JSON

```
public struct HistoryModel{
    var fk_user_id: String?
    var signature: String?
    var fk_cores_id: String?
    var name: String?
    var inspections_id: String?
    var fk_project_surveyors_id: String?
    var created_date: String?
    var number: String?
    var survey_date: String?
    var sub_cores: [SubCoreModelData]
    
    public init(fk_user_id: String,signature: String,fk_cores_id: String,name: String,inspections_id: String,fk_project_surveyors_id: String,created_date: String,number: String,survey_date: String,sub_cores:[SubCoreModelData]) {
        self.fk_user_id = fk_user_id
        self.signature = signature
        self.fk_cores_id = fk_cores_id
        self.name = name
        self.inspections_id = inspections_id
        self.fk_project_surveyors_id = fk_project_surveyors_id
        self.created_date = created_date
        self.number = number
        self.survey_date = survey_date
        self.sub_cores = sub_cores
    }
}

public struct SubCoreModelData{
    var sub_core_title: String?
    
    public init(sub_core_title: String?) {
        self.sub_core_title = sub_core_title
    }
}
```

and here is my code API call function from which i am storing data to an array

var historyData = HistoryModel

```
func historyAPI(){
        guard let uid = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "uid") else { return }
        guard let accessToken = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "accToken") else { return }
        guard let projectid = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "propSurID") else { return }
        
        let params = ["user_id": uid, "access_token": accessToken,"project_surveyors_id": projectid,"cores_id": self.coreid]
        print(params)
        showHud(view: self.view, message: "Please Wait")
        AF.request(previousinspectionlist, method: .post, parameters: params).responseJSON(completionHandler: {(response) in
            switch response.result{
            case.success(let value):
                let json  = JSON(value)
                print(json)
                let data = json["data"]
                if data == []{
    
                }else{
                    self.historyData.removeAll()
                    for cat in data{
                        let fk_user_id = cat.1["fk_user_id"].stringValue
                        let name = cat.1["name"].stringValue
                        let signature = cat.1["signature"].stringValue
                        let fk_cores_id = cat.1["fk_cores_id"].stringValue
                        let inspections_id = cat.1["inspections_id"].stringValue
                        let fk_project_surveyors_id = cat.1["fk_project_surveyors_id"].stringValue
                        let created_date = cat.1["created_date"].stringValue
                        let number = cat.1["number"].stringValue
                        let survey_date = cat.1["survey_date"].stringValue


                        var arrOfItems = [SubCoreModelData]()
                        for ser in cat.1["sub_cores"] {
                            let subcore = SubCoreModelData(sub_core_title: ser.1["sub_cores_title"].stringValue)
                            arrOfItems.append(subcore)
                        }
                        self.historyData.append(HistoryModel(fk_user_id: fk_user_id, signature: signature, fk_cores_id: fk_cores_id, name: name, inspections_id: inspections_id, fk_project_surveyors_id: fk_project_surveyors_id, created_date: created_date, number: number, survey_date: survey_date, sub_cores: arrOfItems, collapsed: false))
                    }
                }
                self.tblListView.reloadData()
                dismissHud()
            case.failure(let error):
                basicErrorAlertWith(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription, controller: self)
                dismissHud()
            }
        })
    }
```

but with this code i am getting duplicate data in tableview so can anyone please tell me how to set tags to each row which has Sub Core title please help me for this

**TableviewDelegate And DataSource Code**

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.historyData.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let items = self.historyData[section].sub_cores
    return items.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! InspectionHistoryTableViewCell
    cell.lblName.text = historyData[indexPath.row].name
    if let number = historyData[indexPath.row].number{
        print(number)
        cell.lblNumber.text = "#\(number)"
    }
    cell.lblSurveydate.text = historyData[indexPath.row].survey_date
    let items = self.historyData[indexPath.section].sub_cores
    let item = items[indexPath.row]
    if let subcore = item.sub_core_title{
        cell.tagList.addTag(subcore)
    }
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Could you show the code in func cellForRowAtIndexPath ?

Comment: @goat_herd Please check i have updated code

Comment: @goat_herd have checked code in cellForRoAtIndexPath? than please help me

Comment: Sorry for late but seem you have answer, happy coding

Comment: @goat_herd Yes i got the answer and thanks for supporting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are confusing your data model.
It looks like for each entry in the `historyData` you have a section, and for each `sub_cores` in that history data you want a row.

But what you really want is just one section, with `historyData.count` rows.

In `cellForRowAt:` you are accessing the history data array with both row and section index, which will lead to a mixture of data and is highly likely to crash soon.

So to correct your `cellForRowAt:`, you need to just access the history data per row index, and the clar and fill the tag view with all sub_cores.

This should work:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.historyData.count
}

func tableView (_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell    = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! InspectionHistoryTableViewCell
    let row     = indexPath.row
    let data    = historyData[row]
    
    cell.lblName.text = data.name

    if let number = data.number{
        print(number)
        cell.lblNumber.text = "#\(number)"
    }
    
    cell.lblSurveydate.text = data.survey_date
    let items = data.sub_cores
    cell.tagList.removeAllTags()
    for (item in items) {
        cell.tagList.addTag(item.sub_core_title)
    }
    
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    return cell
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me what i should return in `numberOfSections` & `numberOfRowsInSection`

Comment: That looks fine for me. At least, if you want sections and rows. If you want just a single (flat) section, it get more complicated

Comment: Okay but there is one more issue when i scroll tableview then it shows me duplicates is their any solution for this?